# PHP installation conflicts on Centos6

Tags: php, centos6

I'm new to server and linux and I ran into some problems. I'm trying to update my PHP by looking for linux commands through the net. Some commands ran perfectly but some not.

I tried using this command to install php-gd since I have this error message 'Required GD library is missing'. So, I tried to run this below:

```
yum install php-gd
```

However, it give me this error message below:

```
php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
```

Here are some info on my server:

```
[root@uat ~]# rpm -ql php
package php is not installed

[root@uat ~]# rpm -qa php\*
php56w-pdo-5.6.11-1.w6.x86_64
php56w-5.6.11-1.w6.x86_64
php56w-cli-5.6.11-1.w6.x86_64
php56w-common-5.6.11-1.w6.x86_64
php56w-mysql-5.6.11-1.w6.x86_64

[root@uat ~]# rpm -Va php\*
S.5....T.  c /etc/php.ini
[root@uat ~]# which php
/usr/bin/php

[root@uat ~]# php -v
PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul 10 2015 22:43:20)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Do you know what have I done wrong upgrading my php? Should I remove all php files on my server and reinstall? How?

Comment: already solved the problem by running " yum install php56w-gd.x86_64
"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved it by removing all php using "yum remove php php-common"

and modified the filename "remi.repo" under the folder /etc/yum.repos.d like below:

```
[remi-php56]
name=Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php56/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php56/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

making sure that php56 is enabled=1.

Answer (score 3):

You should run:

```
yum install php56w-gd
```

So when install `php-extension` have error:

```
*-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
```

Just type `*-extension`

Example:

`yum install php-fpm` have error

```
Error: php56u-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64
```

then you should run

```
yum install php56u-fpm
```

The reason of this error is you install a php version don't match the system repo version. So yum get a version of the system repo, but this don't compatible with the php version you have installed. When you specific the php version, yum get the right version, so happy!

Answer (score 2):

Go to /etc/yum.repos.d.
Remove the extra repository that you can see in your complete error message.
Nima

Comment: here is what I see and not sure which repo to remove/comment out.

`yum install php-common`

    `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
    Setting up Install Process
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
     * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
     * extras: mirror.netdepot.com
     * ius: mirror.symnds.com
     * updates: mirror.cogentco.com
     * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com`

`Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64`
    _You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem_

Comment: I tried `yum update` as well, before tying to install `php-mbstring`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Centos 6.7 and have php 5.6 installed, the following command worked for me:

`sudo yum install php56w-pecl-xdebug.x86_64` (I was installing xdebug, not GD)

I found this by running `yum search php56`