# Upgraded PHP to 5.6.16 and MySQL Extension not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was running a very outdated version of `PHP` version 5.3.3. So I updated it to 5.6.16. However since I've updated I am getting the following error when I try to view my `Wordpress` site:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

I understand that the reason for this error is because the `mysql extension` is not being loaded by PHP but I am unsure as to what to do to get this? I've checked my `php.ini` file and uncommented this line

```
extension=msql.so
```

restarted my apache server and no luck!

The Code I am using to check if it is enabled is:

```
if (extension_loaded('mysql') or extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
            echo "Loaded";
        }else{
            echo "Not Loaded";
        }
```

when I run `php -m` in my terminal I see mysql is not listed.
Could anyone help me out with getting this to work.

I've also tried running this command `yum install php-mysql` but I get this error:

```
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.i686
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thanks

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580464/php-installation-conflicts-on-centos6

Comment: On the server must be installed `mysql-client`, `libmysqlclient`,`php*-mysql`. Then you need restart your Apache/Nginx or `# php -m` and be sure that you enable `mysql.so` extension in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Have you tried `yum install php56w-mysql`?

Comment: Rob that worked!! Thank you very much, what exactly does that command do? Installs PHP with the MySQL extension??

Comment: I've added that as an answer for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried yum install php56w-mysql?

That should install the 5.6 version of the MySQL libraries. It looks like yum is trying to install the 5.3 version by default. Out of curiosity, what OS is this you are installing on, it might be a little out of date.

Comment: I am installing this on server running 
Linux 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.i686 i686

Comment: That is quite old, it is supported I believe though. A more recent distribution will have a newer kernel version and also be set up to use more up to date php libraries/repositories.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the process of also trying to update my Kernal to version 2.6.32-573. Thank you for your help