# PHP not executing - just showing as plain text

Tags: php, apache

I've encountered this problem before and been able to resolve it, but that is not the case now.

I followed some instructions to upgrade PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6 and now PHP files simply show the source in the browser.

I've added the following lines to httpd.conf

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

But this doesn't fix the issue.
Some other advice I've read is to use `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`
however there is no libphp5.so file on my system, and I've read elsewhere that this advice is not right anyway

What else can I try?

The answers at [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)  don't appear to apply, for example as I've mentioned libphp5.so doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Yes I've read that one already

Comment: Start by taking a look into your http servers error log file when it starts up. Anything of interest there about loading php?

Comment: Check if `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` lists `php5_module` as one of the loaded modules

Comment: What is the extension of your PHP files? Do you have that extension allowed in the config?

Comment: arkascha:  No not in the error logs but if I do php -v I see errors like "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so' - /usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0" but I think those has been there all along.      apokryfos No I don't see it.   Legionar .php and isn't that what the AddHandler and AddType lines do ?

Comment: of course `.php`, but you can also use f.e. `.phtml` or whatever else.

Comment: how was php installed?

Comment: I used this to upgrade from 5.3 to 5.6 http://superuser.com/questions/615401/upgrading-php-5-3-3-to-5-4-4-in-centos-6-4  and I've also done yum remove php-cli and yum install php-cli since posting this question - no change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

```
yum remove php php-common
```

then reconfiguring remi.repo according to the answer at:

[PHP installation conflicts on Centos6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580464/php-installation-conflicts-on-centos6)

I didn't actually have a remi.repo so I used

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/remi.repo
```

and then `yum install php php-common`

and restarted httpd.

what a headache